# PHP passing variable to a function in another file

Tags: php, function, variables

**index.php**

```
require '../include/FunctionFile.php';
$test = "blah";
myfunction($test);
```

**FunctionFile.php**

```
function myfunction($test){
    global $test;
    echo $test;
}
```

I want to pass `$test` value to myfunction but look like it's not working, it's return nothing, nothing in error log.

Comment: is your `myfunction` part of a class? or just simple written function

Comment: @urfusion no, it's a simple function

Comment: are you sure that the file with the functions is being included correctly?

Comment: is filepath of FunctionFile.php correct?
It is working in my end.

Comment: @RamRaider yes, i'm sure

Comment: @VipinSingh yeah it's correct, I'm sure

Comment: as a test try adding `echo function_exists( 'myFunction' ) ? 'Yes' : 'No';` to the page where you try to call the function ~ there's nothing obvious as to why it would not work as it is

Comment: Nice way to test, it return `yes` @RamRaider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function need `return` value.

**index.php**

```
require '../include/FunctionFile.php';
$test = "blah";
$var=myfunction($test);// assign to vaiable
echo $var;
```

**FunctionFile.php**

```
function myfunction($test){
    return $test;// use return type here
}
```

Comment: use this to check error in page `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: apologize for prev reply! it was my wrong, it working fine.. Thanks

Comment: nice one @Saty: great answer

Answer (score 1):

I know other mate already provided the solution, so i am adding my answer for **future aspects**.

Suppose you have two functions `getHello()` and `getGoodbye()` with different definition same purpose.

```
// function one
function getHello(){
    return "Hello";
}

// function two
function getGoodbye(){
    echo "Goodbye";
}

//now call getHello() function
$helloVar = getHello();
```

**Result:**

```
'Hello' // return 'hello' and stored value in $helloVar

//now call getGoodbye() function
$goodbyeVar = getGoodbye();
```

**Result:**

```
'Goodbye' // echo 'Goodbye' and not stored in $goodbyeVar

echo $helloVar; // "Hello" 
echo $goodbyeVar; // Goodbye
```

**Result:**

```
'GoodbyeHello'

// now try same example with this:

echo $helloVar; // "Hello" 
//echo $goodbyeVar; // Goodbye
```

Result should be same because `getGoodbye()` already `echo'ed` the result.

**Now Example with Your Code:**

```
function myfunction($test){
    //global $test;
    echo $test;
}

function myfunction2($test){
    //global $test;
    return $test;
}

myfunction('test'); // test
myfunction2('test'); // noting

//You need to echo myfunction2() as i mentioned in above.

echo myfunction2('test'); // test
```

**Why it's not working in your code?:**

you need to declare variable as `Global` before assigning the values like:

```
global $test;
$test = "blah";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```js
myfunction("args");
function myfunction($test){
 echo $test;
}
```